# Voice Home Lab Cisco Devices

Tags: voice

I have following configuration for my home lab -

[image]

I have configured 4 VLAN interfaces - 10.10.10.10(R1-Vlan 100), 20.20.20.20(R2-Vlan 200), 30.30.30.30(R3-Vlan 300) and 40.40.40.40(R4-Vlan 400). There is one Routing Interface(192.168.1.10) on switch which is connected to my WiFi DSL Modem so that I can access everything over WiFi also. From the Switch I am able to telnet to all the routers, but my problem is regarding configuration for accessing Server(4 Virtual Machines). I want to access server over remote desktop connection and also want to use server for SPAN, and I want to provide internet access to the server. How should I configure VLAN on my switch and how will be the routing done?
Switch - 3550
Routers - 2811.

Thanks.
Manish

Comment: What do you intend for the routers? I don't understand why you have four routers for this since a single router can accomplish what you seem to want to do. A router with only one network attached is pretty useless since routers route between networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Activate ip routing on the 3550 switch (in configuration mode enter the "ip routing" command) .
- On R1-R4 set the switch as the default gateway (gateway of last resort ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 [ip address of switch interface]).
- Set the switch as default gateway on the VMs
- On the switch set the DSL Modem as gateway of last resort commad: ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 [ip address of the dsl modem]

So in conclusion the switch need an ip in the vlan and the routers.
If the routers will access other Subnets they go to the switch and the switch will route the packet to the other subnet (in its routing table interfaces will appear as connected).

If I understand it right you want the VMs in different VLANs and have only one physical intherface attached to the server?

--> go to the switch configure the attached port as trunk

I hope it will work (=

Comment: The 3550 may not be a layer-3 switch, so the `ip routing` command may not work. The switch should not be used as a default gateway unless it is a layer-3 switch. You shouldn't set a default gateway on a router; that is a rookie mistake; router route, and should use routing protocols. You could set a static default route.

Comment: @RonMaupin ip routing works on that :)

Comment: @MUSR, then why do you need the other routers? A layer-3 switch is a router. This whole design makes no sense to do what you want done.

Comment: I read the documentation of cisco to get the information if it could root bevor I gave my comment

Comment: @RonMaupin it is a home lab for ccnp collaboration, so i need them :) Routers are not there for routing.

Comment: You do not use `default gateway` on a router unless routing is disabled. This is what the Cisco documentation says: "_Use the ip default-gateway command when ip routing is disabled on a Cisco router. Use the ip default-network and ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 commands to set the gateway of last resort on Cisco routers that have ip routing enabled. The way in which routing protocols propagate the default route information varies for each protocol._" Using `default gateway` is a rookie mistake.

Comment: @MUSR, to do what you want in your question, the routers are irrelevant since you can route on the switch. You only need the switch and the server. VM configurations are off-topic here. Your question of setting up a lab is too broad since the lab needs to be configured, and reconfigured, for individual exercises, and all "_education, certification, or homework_" questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @Pompi which IP Address should be default gateway for VMs?

Comment: The switch have an interface every vlan or? So if one vm is in vlan 1 the default Gateway IP address of this vm would be the switches vlan 1 IP address

Comment: VM is not in any vlan now, but I got the idea. Thanks.

Comment: Ah Ok. Sorry i think i havnt totaly und er stand, in which subnet you want to have your vms

Comment: I am thinking of putting VMs in a new subnet with subinterfaces(if it won't create any future problems) or all VMs in one subnet with a vlan interface(this one seems easier)

Comment: To my knowledge the VMs could handle this (the switchport interface have to be trunk then, if you have only one link from the server to the switch [command in switches portinterface: "switchport mode trunk"). And you need further vlan interfaces with the corresponding ip address, because you need also an default gateway ip address for the VMs :P

Comment: Let me try all the possibilities. I will let you know which suits me better :)